# Create and populate field with name of feature (Select by Location) ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, select-by-location, error-000358

I am staring at 5600 individual points and 60 polygons. I need to create a new field in the point fc called 'Basin Name' and populate the field with the name of the Basin that it lies in. I am trying to develop a reusable script that can be used weekly to accomplish newly inputed points. I have two features, SSO which are points and Basins which are polygons. I have tried to follow this thread ([Assigning field value based on location without join](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108341/assigning-field-value-based-on-location-without-join)) but I keep receiving an error on the SelectLayerByAttributes.

The error I receive is "Runtime error Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 19, in  File "j:\apps\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 7221, in SelectLayerByAttribute raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute)."

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "Y:/SSO_BASINS/"

# Set overwrite option
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# KEEPING ORIGINAL LAYERS (NOT CREATING ADDITIONAL "JOINED" LAYER)
# Create FeatureLayers
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Y:/SSO_BASINS/Basins.shp", "lyr_Basins")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Y:/SSO_BASINS/SSO.shp", "lyr_SSO")

# Add a "BASIN" field  
arcpy.AddField_management("lyr_SSO", "BASIN", "TEXT")

# Create a search cursor for the states
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("lyr_Basins")
for row in rows:
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lyr_Basins", "NEW_SELECTION", 
"\"OBJECTID\"  " + str(row.getValue("OBJECTID")))
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("lyr_SSO", "INTERSECT", "lyr_Basins", 
"", "NEW_SELECTION")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("lyr_SSO", "BASIN", 
"'{0}'".format(str(row.getValue("BASIN"))), "PYTHON_9.3", "")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using ArcMap 10.3 you should use the `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` instead of the deprecated `arcpy.SearchCursor`. Also, your `arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management` syntax is backward. You are selecting within your `lyr_SSO` layer when you want to be selecting within the `lyr_Basins` feature. The `SelectLayerByAttribute_management` step is unnecessary since you are already looping through the rows. You can use the `SHAPE@` field as your selection location.

```python
import arcpy

# Set overwrite option
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# KEEPING ORIGINAL LAYERS (NOT CREATING ADDITIONAL "JOINED" LAYER)
# Create FeatureLayers
lyr_basin = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Y:/SSO_BASINS/Basins.shp", "lyr_Basins")
lyr_sso = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Y:/SSO_BASINS/SSO.shp", "lyr_SSO")

# Add a "BASIN" field  
arcpy.AddField_management(lyr_sso, "BASIN", "TEXT")

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(lyr_sso, ["BASIN", "SHAPE@"]) as ssoCursor:
    for row in ssoCursor:
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(lyr_basin, "INTERSECT", row[1], "", "NEW_SELECTION")
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr_basin, ["BASIN"]) as basCursor:
            for brow in basCursor:
                row[0] = brow[0]
                ssoCursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates a bad SQL statement.

You want something like this:

`"OBJECTID" = 7`

Your code (`"\"OBJECTID\"  " + str(row.getValue("OBJECTID"))`) will yield this:

`"OBJECTID" 7`

Change your code to include the equal sign:

`"\"OBJECTID\" = " + str(row.getValue("OBJECTID"))`

I like `.format` for a bit cleaner code:

`'"OBJECTID" = {}'.format (row.getValue("OBJECTID"))`

Also, your field calculate expression is going to produce an error because you use single quotes instead of double quotes.

Your code:

`"'{0}'".format(str(row.getValue("BASIN")))`

needs a quick fix:

`'"{0}"'.format(str(row.getValue("BASIN")))`

At the end of the day though, I'd skip the cursor and the iterating of rows and just use a [Spatial Join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm).

Comment: I went with Jacob's answer and it worked. The spatial join is simple enough, but with it possibly being a reoccuring task, a script is ideal. Thanks, Emil!

Comment: You can script a spatial join, of course.